# PyCharm show graphics

Tags: python, windows, pycharm

I am trying to have PyCharm show my graphics, but when I run this script nothing appears on the screen.

```
from pylab import *

def main():
    ion()
    t = arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
    s = sin(2*pi*t)
    plot(t, s)

    xlabel('time (s)')
    ylabel('voltage (mV)')
    title('About as simple as it gets, folks')
    grid(True)    
    show()
```

I am using Python 2.7.6, Pycharm 3.4 and Windows 7 x64.

---

```
D:\Python27\python.exe "D:/sletmig/python tests/pandas/chart.py"

Process finished with exit code 0
```

---

I am new to Python!

Comment: where are you calling `main` function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this to the end of script:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```